# how to add router transition in gatsby programmatic navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

In my gatsby website,

I have a search bar and when a suggestion is clicked, `handleClick` runs and I navigate them to the suggested page. To change route, I used `navigate("/my-link")`. now how can I add router transition on gatsby programmatic navigation?

Comment: Have you tried using [the approach documented in the official Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-page-transitions-with-plugin-transition-link/)?

Answer (score -1):

Gatsby uses Reach Router [under the hood](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/reach-router-and-gatsby/) for routing.

The official documentation has an [example](https://reach.tech/router/example/animation) on how to animate page transitions.

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <nav className="nav">
      <Link to="/">Page 1</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="page/2">Page 2</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="page/3">Page 3</Link>{" "}
      <Link to="page/4">Page 4</Link>
    </nav>

    <FadeTransitionRouter>
      <Page path="/" page="1" />
      <Page path="page/:page" />
    </FadeTransitionRouter>
  </div>
);

const FadeTransitionRouter = props => (
  <Location>
    {({ location }) => (
      <TransitionGroup className="transition-group">
        <CSSTransition key={location.key} classNames="fade" timeout={500}>
          {/* the only difference between a router animation and
              any other animation is that you have to pass the
              location to the router so the old screen renders
              the "old location" */}
          <Router location={location} className="router">
            {props.children}
          </Router>
        </CSSTransition>
      </TransitionGroup>
    )}
  </Location>
);
```